# AOP-Based Persistence, Transactions & Messaging by Example

Tags: java, transactions, persistence, aop, message

I'm really starting to wrap my head around AOP and really like the idea of abstracting out cross-cutting concerns and removing it from my core business code. So far I've been reading up on AOP Alliance (which I see is the workhorse for Guice and Spring AOP) and AspectJ.

Unfortunately, good, working Java AOP code examples are hard to come by when we are talking about anything more advanced than simple method interception. I keep reading over and over again how major Java EE concepts such as Persistence, Transaction Handling and Messaging can be implemented with AOP, but for the life of me I can't find any examples of this!

Ultimately speaking, at the end of the day, AOP does just boil down to method interception (unless I'm missing something *major* here). So if that's the case, and given the general form of a method interceptor:

```
// Using AOP Alliance for this example
public class MyInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {
    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation inv) {
        // Run this code before executing inv.
        preInvocation();

        Object result = inv.proceed();

        // Run this code after executing inv.
        postInvocation();
    }

    // ...
}
```

Given that as a starting point, can someone please provide **concrete** code examples for how each of these Java EE concepts can be delegated to AOP via method interception:

- Persistence/ORM
- Transaction Handling
- Messaging

I guess I'm just having difficulty connecting all the dots and seeing the "forest" through the "trees". Thanks in advance!

Comment: As exciting as AOP can be at first, just be careful about the consequences of "automagic" in code...  We have found that it can be terribly frustrating/confusing to other developers on your team that don't have as solid of a handle on it.  Like all things, it is great in moderation.

Comment: I really recommend using annotations for this as opposed to pure out of code AOP weaving, it's just easier to follow. Any interest in that, or are you really looking for an example where thread-local variables with transaction information live? I'm not sure what AOP would add to messaging exactly, what are you looking for there?

Comment: I'm *brand* new to AOP and am trying to see working code examples of the things I've been [reading about](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cutting_concern). Yes, I absolutely want to end up using annotations (method interception) instead of bytecode weaving for several reasons. What I'm looking for is an example of an AOP method interceptor that could be used for persistence or messaging (meaning, when a method executes, it is intercepted and some kind of persistence- or messaging-oriented code executes as its advice).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No idea for persistence and messaging, but for transactions, I can explain. I'll take the example of Spring.

You can configure your Spring beans (typically service layer beans) so that every method invoked on those beans will be intercepted by a transactional interceptor. This interceptor typically does the following thing:

- see if a transaction is already bound to the current thread
- if not, start a transaction and bind it to the current thread
- invoke the method
- if the transaction was started by this method interception and no runtime exception was thrown by the method, commit the transaction
- if the transaction was started by this method interception and a runtime exception was thrown by the method, rollback the transaction
- unbind the transaction from the current thread

With no transactional aspect the transactional methods would have to do something like this:

```
try {
    userTransaction.begin();
    executeSomeBusinessCode();
    userTransaction.commit();
}
catch (RuntimeException e) {
    userTransaction.rollback();
}
```

It's cumbersome, error-prone, and doesn't even handle transaction propagation, new transactions, etc.

With AOP, the body of the method becomes:

```
executeSomeBusinessCode();
```

Comment: Thanks @JB.  +1 for the excellent Transaction example but I'm looking for persistence and messaging examples and none have been provided thus far.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by 'messaging' and 'persistence' - what messages do you want to send? what do you want to persist?

If you want to persist the results of method calls its pretty straight-forward, implement a MethodInterceptor:

```
public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
    Object result = invocation.proceed();
    myPersistenceMethod(invocation, result);
    return result;
}
```

Then you can define an annotation and have method results persisted for annotated methods. E.g. in a Guice module:

```
 bindInterceptor(Matchers.any(), Matchers.annotatedWith(MyPersistenceAnnotation.class),
            new MyPersistenceInterceptor());
```

The main issue is how to construct your persistence 'keys' - the most obvious thing to do is to you the invocation method and arguments, but since this is all reflection based there is no compile time checking if you start assuming certain methods have certain arguments.

How that helps.